# About permissions on files

Tags: android

I want to start writing an app that needs to write files or delete or modify them. I want to ask if anybody knows about the permissions I need? Or does android let you to delete files anyway or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 places where you can save your data. Internal and external storage. Internal Storage is only accessible by your app. The data specific to internal storage will be deleted when the app is deleted.

Given the permissions in your manifest you can have read and write permissions. If you have those permissions you add/edit/delete any data on external storage.

Comment: by the internal and external storage do you mean internal and SD card?

Comment: android originally had external as sdcard. But some devices now divide the memory into internal and external storage. That is the reason we check if external is available and we do not asume a path and call  Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();